# Reaching crease and then step out

Tags: cricket

Batsmen 1 hit the ball and take one run. So batsman 2 run, reached his crease but the step out to collect his bat that he have dropped. In this he gets stumped. Is he out ?

Comment: He cannot be Stumped as he is the non-striker.  He is Run Out.

Comment: @Nij - I disagree about the close vote. I read this question as the batsman has already made their ground, and has subsequently left their ground to collect their bat. Whereas the question you have linked as a dupe - is about the batsman making their ground in the first place.

Comment: The questions aren't the point, the answer is, and that answer resolved this question.